# How to get 1 directory result in directory listing in PHP

Tags: php, foreach, directory

How to get 1 directory result in directory listing.

Example:

```
Directory List:
aa            ===  its directory
  ah          ===  its sub-directory
  ah          ===  its sub-directory

bb            ===  its directory
  blah          ===  its sub-directory
  blah          ===  its sub-directory
```

I wanted look like.

```
aa | ah ==  latest modified directory.
bb | blah ==  latest modified directory.
```

Here is code.

```
$dirs = array_filter(glob('dir/*/*'), 'is_dir');
array_multisort(array_map('filemtime', $dirs), SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC, $dirs);
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense.

Comment: hehee. i want to get 1 result per last updated directory.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Comment you answered on your Question, I think what you search is to reduce Duplicates in your Array. This is done by a Simple Array Function:
array_unique

http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

this Removes all Duplicates. Applied to your shown Arrays it will only show 1 Array Entry per Value.

Comment: Thanks for good function. But its not works on GLOB(); that function check unique values so if 2 directories has same number its ignore it?